# undefined reference to `bool Script::get<bool>(char const*)'

Tags: c++, lua

Есть код(напиасан с использованием туториала https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/lua_cpp_binder/):

```
class Script{
    public:
        void create(const char *file);
        void close();
        void run();
        template <typename T> T get(const char *var);
    private:
        template <typename T> T lua_get(const string& variableName);
        template <typename T> T lua_get(const char *var){ return 0; }
        bool lua_gettostack(const string& variableName);
        lua_State *_L;
};

...

template <typename T> T EGE_Script::get(const char *var){
    if(!_L) {
        EGE_SetError("Script is not loaded");
        return "null";
    }

    T _result;
    if(lua_gettostack(string(var))){
        _result = lua_get<T>(string(var));
    } else {
        _result = "null";
    }

    return _result;
}

...

bool happy = Script.get<bool>("happy");
```

Не знаю, что не так? Вот что говорит компилятор:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `bool Script::get<bool>(char const*)'
```

Comment: А не положили ли вы template'ный метод в .cpp-файл?

Comment: да, положил. Нельзя?

Comment: Нет. Сейчас напишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, в чём проблема.

Шаблонные методы — это не настоящие методы. Это лишь заготовка, из которой в момент инстанциации (то есть, в тот момент, когда компилятор читает `get<bool>`) производится настоящий метод.

В этот момент для создания метода требуется код. Если код недоступен, то компилятор не может создать метод, но он надеется, что вы знаете, что делаете.

Если вы положите шаблонный метод в `.h`, то во всех точках, где он будет вызываться, код будет виден. Если же вы перенесёте метод в .cpp, как это полагается делать для обычных методов, то в точке, где компилятор видит вызов конкретного шаблонного метода, у него не будет из чего составить тело метода.

Это неустранимое ограничение модели компиляции C++. Оно удостоилось даже упоминания в [официальном C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-class-defn-from-decl).

Поэтому решение проблемы — перенести реализацию метода в заголовочный файл.

---

Популярный workaround для случая, если вам очень-очень не хочется выносить код из .cpp-файла, который сработает, если вам *наперёд* известно, с какими типами будет инстанциирован шаблонный метод — оставить код в .cpp и *вручную* проинстанциировать все нужные шаблоны. Например, так, как описано в ответе @ixSci. Если ваш компилятор старый, сгодится такая конструкция:

```
namespace
{
    void dummy_instatiate()
    {
        Script* script = nullptr;
        script->get<bool>();
        script->get<int>();
        script->get<std::string>();
    }
}
```

(и никогда не вызывать эту функцию). Это заставит компилятор сгенерировать код для инстанциаций шаблона с параметром `bool`, `int` и `std::string`, так что с этими типами шаблоном можно будет пользоваться. Но не с другими.

Comment: а в .hpp можно?

Comment: @egordorichev: Да. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Немного не понял: зачем этот метод? Как он влияет? Но сработало )

Comment: @egordorichev: Ну, компилятор, когда видит этот метод, может создать нужную инстанциацию шаблона (потому что код метода в этой точке виден). И создаёт! В других точках он не может создать её, т. к. не видит код метода.

Comment: т.е., для инстанцирования шаблона Вы создаете `dummy_instatiate`? По той же логике, Вы должны его вызвать где-то в программе? Думаю, Вы сильно поспешили, спрятав это решение под красивым заголовком "Популярный workaround" )))

Comment: @mega: Нет, почему же. Инстанциирование шаблонного метода происходит во время компиляции.

Comment: И ещё я бы хотел получить комментарий от минусующего.

Comment: Увы, но, думаю, популярное решение все же следует искать по ключевым словам ["Explicit Instantiation"](http://www.google.com/search?q=Explicit+Instantiation)

Comment: @mega: Хм, и правда. Напишите альтернативный ответ?

Comment: @mega: Ну, как-то нехорошо с моей стороны присваивать чужую идею.

Comment: @mega: О, пока мы тут занимались внутренним диалогом... :)

Comment: ну, это же мелочь, лучше уточните свой ответ (по философии SO так будет лучше). У MS по теме есть лаконичная статья: [Function Template Instantiation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k8twfx7.aspx) [поправил ссылку]

Answer (score 1):

Причину @VladD уже описал, я же предложу альтернативное решение данной проблемы. Т.е не workaround, а решение:
Просто добавьте следующее в .cpp файл:

```
template bool Script::get<bool>(const char *var);
```

для каждого типа, что необходим. Это решит проблему с линковщиком.

Comment: Классно! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Только не `void`, а `bool` для вашего случая.